# Combine information from sales flat order and sales flat order item sql Magento

Tags: sql, magento

What would the SQL query be to get the following information in one table?
Order Status
Order Number (Increment ID)
Product Name
Product Type
Manufacturer
Price
Miscellaneous Invoice Information

It looks like this information is in three tables, sales_flat_order, sales_flat_order_item, and sales_flat_invoice.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree with @cleong that you should use Magento’s ORM to load this data in the application, but something like this query might be useful for pulling data for reports, etc:

```
SELECT
    sfo.entity_id,
    sfo.increment_id,
    sfoi.name,
    sfoi.product_type,
    sfoi.price,
    sfoi.original_price,
    sfo.status,
    sfi.state
FROM
    sales_flat_order sfo
INNER JOIN
    sales_flat_order_item sfoi ON sfoi.order_id = sfo.entity_id
LEFT JOIN
    sales_flat_invoice sfi ON sfi.order_id = sfo.entity_id
ORDER BY
    sfo.entity_id DESC
LIMIT
    500
```

You will have to tweak the columns to get exactly what you want, and notably this only includes data that can be pulled from order info. If you want to refer back to data that can only be found in the catalog — which can be risky since old products may no longer exist and often requires getting into the EAV model — more joins will be necessary.

Comment: This is great and it has everything except the manufacturer name.  Any way to get that as well?

Comment: @eonblue2 - It depends, that isn’t included in the order info normally so it might require cross-linking from the catalog, and that is much more dependent on your particular setup.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to have an SQL query like that but that is too complex. OOP of Magento allows you to retrieve these attributes using methods, so all you need would to call is to getOrderID() etc on the appropriate objects.

Comment: I'm not sure how to use OOP of magento.  I've seen people use the PHP code, but I'm not sure exactly where to put it or run it.  I'm a bit of a beginner with this.  Thanks for the help.